# Installing Matlab 2012a (32-bit) in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS java problem

Tags: java, shared-library, matlab

This is my first posting here, so please be gentle. I am having a problem installing Matlab 2012a (32-bit) in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I have trawled around the web and have seen similar problems reported, but I cannot seem to get around the issue, my problem is very similar to the one reported here:

http://www.mathworks.in/matlabcentral/answers/42988-installing-matlab-2012a-in-ubuntu-12-04-java-problem

Except that I get an error message that refers to the java module located in `glnx86:  /tmp/mathworks_2247/sys/java/jre/glnx86/jre rather than glnxa64`.

Here is my problem.

I have installed the Matlab installation software here:

```
/home/usr/Desktop/Matlab_installation
```

I first used `chmod +x install` to convert the install file to an executable file. I then used the `sudo ./install -v` command to install matlab. Here is the output:

```
sudo ./install -v
[sudo] password for usr: 
Preparing installation files ...
->  DVD                 = /home/usr/Desktop/Matlab_installation

->  ARCH                = glnx86

->  DISPLAY             = :0

->  TESTONLY            = 0

->  JRE_LOC             = /tmp/mathworks_2247/sys/java/jre/glnx86/jre

->  LD_LIBRARY_PATH     = /tmp/mathworks_2247/bin/glnx86

Command to run:
/tmp/mathworks_2247/sys/java/jre/glnx86/jre/bin/java  -splash:"/home/usr/Desktop/Matlab_installation/java/splash.png" -Djava.ext.dirs=/tmp/mathworks_2247/sys/java/jre/glnx86/jre/lib/ext:/tmp/mathworks_2247/java/jar:/tmp/mathworks_2247/java/jarext:/tmp/mathworks_2247/java/jarext/axis2/:/tmp/mathworks_2247/java/jarext/guice/:/tmp/mathworks_2247/java/jarext/webservices/ com/mathworks/professionalinstaller/Launcher -root "/home/usr/Desktop/Matlab_installation" -tmpdir "/tmp/mathworks_2247" 

Installing ...
/tmp/mathworks_2247/sys/java/jre/glnx86/jre/bin/java: error while loading shared libraries: libjli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Finished
```

I then attempted the command `chmod +x /sys/java/jre/glnx86/jre/java` to convert Matlab's Java to an executable.

I have tried this in a number of ways from navigating through the directory structure in the terminal window (and converting) to using the point and click navigation system and right clicking on Java and converting it to an executable. All of these work fine, the file appears as an executable file, here is how the java file appears using `ls -l`:

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 usr usr  47308 Sep 13 13:23 java
```

it is clearly listed as executable. However, I continue to get the error message:

```
Installing ...
/tmp/mathworks_2387/sys/java/jre/glnx86/jre/bin/java: error while loading shared libraries: libjli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Finished
```

when using `sudo ./install`. What am I doing wrong? I have tried systematically converting the java `@/glnx86/jre/bin/java` to an executable (and back again) without success. Notice that in contrast to previous posts I seem to be having an issue with the `glnx86` java rather than the `glnxa64`, could this be the source of the problem?

Any help would be gratefully received.
regards

Comment: Is your computer a 32 or 64-bit architecture? And, your Ubuntu version?

Comment: Also, add codetags or <pre></pre> to improve the readability of your question.

Comment: The computer is 32 bit architecture

Comment: I wanted to wait to check on machine, all I can find is that the version of Ubuntu is 12.04 LTS

Answer (score 1):

I use matlab too, if this problem with LD_LIBRARY_PATH, maybe this can help u.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/runtime/glnx86:/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/bin/glnx86:/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011a/sys/java/jre/glnx86/jre/lib/i386/client":$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH and reinstall,

Comment: Sorry Panji, is this something you would try after you have managed to install Matlab, I dont even seem to be able to get that far. Have I misunderstood something in your post?

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same issue. You need to add `javadir` to the `install` command.

```
./install -v -javadir <location of jre in your machine>
```