# Installing matlab on Ubuntu 12.04 32bits

Tags: installation, matlab, jre

I am trying to install Matlab on Ubuntu 12.04, I have a 32bits machine. I downloaded the files and set the file install to exectable, then run :

```
$ ./install -v
```

but then I got the error :

```
Error : Cannot locate Java Runtime Environment (JRE).
The directory /Unix_MAC/sys/java/jre/glnx86/jre does not exist.
```

So I decided to add the path of matlab's jre to the command ( But before I went to sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/glnxa64 and changed the file java to executable), then tried :

```
$ ./install -v -javadir /home/mbenseddik/Unix_MAC/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/
```

But then I got the following error :

```
Preparing installation files ...
cp: impossible d'évaluer «/home/mbenseddik/Unix_MAC/bin/glnx86/*»: No such file or directory
->  DVD                 = /home/mbenseddik/Unix_MAC
->  ARCH                = glnx86
->  DISPLAY             = :0.0
->  TESTONLY            = 0
->  JRE_LOC             = /tmp/mathworks_11294/sys/java/jre/glnx86/jre
->  LD_LIBRARY_PATH     = /tmp/mathworks_11294/bin/glnx86


    Command to run:

/tmp/mathworks_11294/sys/java/jre/glnx86/jre/bin/java -Xmx512m  -splash:"/home/mbenseddik/Unix_MAC/java/splash.png" -Djava.ext.dirs=/tmp/mathworks_11294/sys/java/jre/glnx86/jre/lib/ext:/tmp/mathworks_11294/java/jar:/tmp/mathworks_11294/java/jar/ja_JP/:/tmp/mathworks_11294/java/jar/zh_CN/:/tmp/mathworks_11294/java/jarext:/tmp/mathworks_11294/java/jarext/axis2/:/tmp/mathworks_11294/java/jarext/guice/:/tmp/mathworks_11294/java/jarext/webservices/ com/mathworks/professionalinstaller/Launcher -root "/home/mbenseddik/Unix_MAC" -tmpdir "/tmp/mathworks_11294" 

Installing ...
/tmp/mathworks_11294/sys/java/jre/glnx86/jre/bin/java: 1: /tmp/mathworks_11294/sys/java/jre/glnx86/jre/bin/java: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
Finished
```

It seems like it is looking for glnx86 whereas the only directory inside the sys/java/jre directory is glnx64...

Any idea on the matter ?

Comment: From [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/287991/52726), try `./install -v -javadir <location of jre in your machine>`, so you'd try `./install -v -javadir /home/mbenseddik/Unix_MAC/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/`.

Comment: @Alaa Thanks for your answer, how can I find the location of jre in my machine ?

Comment: `./install -v -javadir /home/mbenseddik/Unix_MAC/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/`, isn't that the directory where you found `glnx64`? I'm just saying you can try the same command you tried in your question, but add the `-javadir` option.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that but it didn't work neither, I'm getting the same error... I thought you were speaking about the jre in my machine and not the one in Matlab's installing folders... I thought it may work if I try using it, but I don't know what is the path to it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, MATLAB 2013a is not compatible with Linux 32 bit. The last release of MATLAB to be compatible with this platform was R2012a.

Comment: how did you know that ?